# How to create the vector sequence 10 12 14 20 22 24 30 32 34 40 42 44 using R

Tags: r

I am trying to create the sequence 0 12 14 20 22 24 30 32 34 40 42 44 using the following way. But it seems not that right because there is a warning message
Warning message:
In a * c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
any one knows other way to do it? cheers

```
a = seq(10, 44, by = 2)
b = a * c(1,1,1,0,0)
b[b!=0]

# > a
# [1] 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44
# > b
# [1] 10 12 14  0  0 20 22 24  0  0 30 32 34  0  0 40 42 44
# > b[b!=0]
# [1] 10 12 14 20 22 24 30 32 34 40 42 44
```

Comment: ```a[c(T, T, T, F, F)]```

Comment: Also `seq(0L, 4L, 2L) + rep(seq(10L, 40L, 10L), each=3)`.

Comment: Hi lmo, what does L mean here? I am green hand for using R. cheers

Comment: Also `c(sapply(seq(10,40,10), function(x) x+c(0,2,4)))` and `c(t(outer(seq(10,40,10), c(0,2,4), "+")))`